# Error during "composer drupal-update" for Drupal 8.0.5

Tags: 8, composer

I've been running a Drupal 8 site since 8.0.0, using the Address module. As this required some CommerceGuys dependencies in the /vendor folder, I've been using the following commands to load dependencies (and update to newer versions of other components):

```
php sites/all/modules/composer_manager/scripts/init.php
composer drupal-update
```

However when I run this for 8.0.5, I'm getting the following error (not all output included):

> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>
> - Removing guzzlehttp/promises (1.0.2)
> - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.0.3)
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>
> - Removing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.1.0)
> - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.1.1)
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>
> - Removing symfony/browser-kit (v2.7.6)
> - Installing symfony/browser-kit (v3.0.3)
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>
> - Removing fabpot/goutte (v3.1.1)
> - Installing fabpot/goutte (v3.1.2)
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>
> - Removing behat/mink (v1.7.0)
> - Installing behat/mink (v1.7.1)
>
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup
>   Script Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup handling the post-package-update event terminated with an exception
>
> [RuntimeException]
>     The directory 'tests' in package 'behat/mink' does not exist.

The CommerceGuys modules components are not getting loaded. I'm not sure if this is because of the above exception.

This has worked for every previous Drupal 8 update, so I'm not sure what's different this time.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/2682003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a patch available here - https://www.drupal.org/node/2664274#comment-10954323, which is RTBC.

I can confirm it's working :)

Comment: Yes, I found the patch and it resolved the problem. Then Drupal 8.0.6 came out a couple of days later. :-)